# How to add spacemacs/evil functions to pulsar-pulse-functions?

Tags: spacemacs, customize, functions

I'm using emacs 28.1 with Spacemacs and after installing [pulsar](https://protesilaos.com/emacs/pulsar) I'm wondering how to add the pulse functionality on certain events, such as, when going through search matches, scrolling up, down, etc.

For example, I usually switch back and forth by `SPC TAB` which maps to `Last buffer`. I found out this ends up being mapped to `spacemacs/alternate-buffer` so I was able to add it to the pulsar-pulse-function list and worked out nicely.

However, for scrolling, usually I do `C-u` or `C-d` which if I'm not mistaken map to `evil-scrol-up/down`. I have tried adding `evil-scroll-up/down` to `(setq pulsar-pulse-function ...)` with no success. `scroll-up/down-command` are also added by default but seems like this is not what spacemacs triggers when doing `C-u` or `C-d`. Note that if I explicitly execute these commands, as `M-x evil-scroll-up/down` pulsar does show the line pulse.

For searching I use evil-search invoking it with `/` then typing the search string and moving around matches with `n` and `N`, I'd also like to have a pulse when going through search matches, but adding `evil-next/previous-match` does not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: This also happen on my vanilla config. I suspect pulsar doesn't support evil nicely, you can ask the author directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by how evil interprets the evil-scroll-up/down command, see also: https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/1659 (Prot has looked at it himself). Hopefully the maintainers from evil can help solve the problem.

EDIT: Prot (the creator of pulsar) has now fixed the issue in the newest version: https://protesilaos.com/emacs/pulsar-changelog

Should be working now if you update the pulsar package.